# Spring JPA doesnt returning generated id value after saving entity through CRUD repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA (CRUD repository) to save my entity class in MS Sql server.
After save, I am not able to retrieve the generated id from my entity class. Anyone, please let me know what could be the issue?

Thanks!!!

Comment: the generated id should automatically be set in the corresponding attribute in your entity. Can you post a sample entity and the code for DB operation?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Hi All...Thanks for your response.  I am able to save my entity and retrieve the id now.

Comment: Can you please post solution code? are you auto generating id value or setting it in controller code?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. What I had to do to get this working was to add "@ GeneratedValue" without the space after the @ sign to the property on my entity that I want to be auto-populated with the database ID.